# Image doesn't scale properly on mobile, but does in responsive window

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage containing several images in a column. During debugging I have now placed only one image, the problem persist.
The problem is, when I use the Chrome Device toolbar, or try to resize the window to very small, the image scales correctly:

[image: Chrome iPhone emulation]

[image: Resizing the Chrome window]

But when I access the page on an actual mobile device, it gets deformed.

[image: Actual iPhone 8 screenshot]

I tried iPhone 7 and 8 and an iPad, chrome and safari on all of them, the problem is the same, the image is always stretched vertically, regardless of what image I use.

My code at the moment:

```
<div class="container contentContainer justify-content-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5 mb-1">
        <img src="..." class="fileImage">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.contentContainer{
height:100%;
margin-top:-56px
padding-top:61px;
padding-bottom:5px;
text-align:center;
}
.fileImage{
display:block; //already an attempt to fix, no effect
height:auto; //same as above
width:100%;
}
```

Any ideas on what causes this and how to fix it are greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I managed to get the image scaled correctly using `object-fit:contain`. When set the cover, it was scaled correctly, but went offscreen no matter what size I tried to set. There is an issue with this as well. I have set a border, to illustrate. My CSS:

```
.fileImage{
object-fit: contain;
object-position: center;
box-sizing:content-box; //again, just an attempt to fix current issue, no effect...
max-width:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Result:
[image: After object-fit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**
So, after like 2 hours of fiddling with different CSS for sizing etc., this CSS and removing the row element worked. I'm not quite sure why, but it did.

```
<div class="container contentContainer justify-content-center">
        <img src="..." class="fileImage mt-5 mb-1">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fileImage{
object-fit: contain;
max-width:100%;
}
```

And works as expected, scales on mobile the same way as in desktop chrome, as per screenshot in original question. Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the meta. Have you defined viewport meta tags in your head tag?